# Clone current scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

Is it possible in Rails to get something like this:

```
scope = MyModel.filter_by({status: 1, color: 'red', user_id: 1})
count_status_2 = scope.clone.unscope(where: :status).where(status: 2)
count_status_3 = scope.clone.unscope(where: :status).where(status: 3)
```

I want to query all records by filter params and also get counts of the other results with almost the same filter, but different statuses. The example above doesn't work, it results in single query with `'status' = 3` in the SQL, so `clone` is not actually cloning here.

Thank you.

UPD.

I'd like to modify not only `where` but the whole scope.
Let's pretend we have list of some men:

`men_scope = User.joins(:jobs, :city).where(sex: 0, age: 20).order(name: :desc)`

and we also want to show `women` button next to that list, containing count of women of the same filter. I'd like to have something like

`women_count = men_scope.uscope(where: :sex).where(sex: 1).count`

but this does change the original `men_scope` so finally I get list of women instead of men.

Comment: is `filter_by` a method you wrote? never seen it before

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady yes, it's just some abstract method that returns scope

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
params = {status: 1, color: 'red', user_id: 1}
a = MyModel.where(params)
b = MyModel.where(params.merge(status: 2))
c = MyModel.where(params.merge(status: 3))
```

or, to use one query do

```
requested_status = params.delete(:status)
x = MyModel.where(params).group(:status)
# And then use something like, not sure how hash will look
a = x[requested_status]
b = x['2']
c = x['3']
```

Comment: That would be too easy. Take a look please at UPD section in topic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 4 you can make use of the [rewhere](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#rewhere) and no need to save scopes

```
filter_1 = MyModel.where({status: 1, color: 'red', user_id: 1})
filter_2 = filter_1.rewhere(status: 2)
filter_3 = filter_1.rewhere(status: 3)
```

Comment: It won't work. It changes `filter_1` deleting `status` from it.

Comment: actually it shouldn't edit the first filter, it returns a new `ActiveRecord::Relation` without editing the first one